# How to and Where to upload Promo videos of app in App Store

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, ios-appstore

I am trying to upload videos that should be listed in the app store.

I  go through many forums. But didn't get a clarified answer.

Can anyone let me know how to upload a video in the app store?

Comment: No instructions on the App Store?

Comment: No, I couldn't able to find anything